How to Properly Handle Navigation and Back Stack Logic in Jetpack Compose Navigation?
I need an implementation that follows this navigation pattern. For example, there are screens a, b, c, and d. The navigation sequence is a > b > d > c > b > d. When we are on screen d and press the back button, the navigation should go as follows: d > b > c > a > exit.
I tried to implement it like this, but it works incorrectly.
@Composable
fun BottomNavBar(navController: NavController, currentDestination: NavDestination?) {
    NavigationBar(modifier = Modifier.height(120.dp)) {
        topLevelRoutes.forEach { topLevelRoute ->
            NavigationBarItem(
                selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any { it.hasRoute(topLevelRoute.route::class) } == true,
                onClick = {
                    if (!navController.popBackStack(topLevelRoute.route, false)) {
                        navController.navigate(topLevelRoute.route) {
                            // Avoid multiple copies of the same destination when
                            // reselecting the same item
                            launchSingleTop = true
                            // Restore state when reselecting a previously selected item
                            restoreState = true
                        }
                    }
                },
                icon = { Icon(topLevelRoute.icon, contentDescription = null) },
                label = { Text(topLevelRoute.name) })
        }
    }
}

